# Merge 2 huge files matching multiple columns and preserving the order (print matching and non-matching values) - scale up from awk

Tags: awk, columns, merge

I'm having trouble with merging data from 2 files. It is genetic data with chromosome, position, reference and alternate alleles and I need to merge the files by matching all 4 of those columns - with the reference and alternate alleles either way round. So I need columns $1,$2,$4 and $5 OR $1,$2,$5 and $4 in the lookup file to exactly match columns $1,$5,$6 and $7 in the datafile. It is really important that I keep the exact order in the datafile - I can't sort it (so sadly can't use join - this is the suggested answer I have found in other instances of this sort of question).

I have used awk and got the code working for sample files with a few thousand rows, but it does not scale up well for my large dataset (lookup file has >300million rows; datafile has 30 million) - presumably as the code requires keeping in memory 2 huge arrays for lookup. Any suggestions for a scaleable code (?in perl?) gratefully received!

Format of lookup file is:

```
1 10150 rs371194064 C T
1 10165 rs796884232 A AC
1 10177 rs367896724 A AC
1 10177 rs201752861 A C
1 10180 rs201694901 T C
1 10199 rs905327004 A T
1 10231 rs200279319 C A
1 10234 rs145599635 C T
1 10235 rs540431307 T TA
1 10235 rs1035249121 T A
1 10235 rs1035249121 T C
1 10241 rs960927773 T C
1 10247 rs796996180 T C
1 10248 rs148908337 A T
1 10249 rs774211241 AAC A
```

and format of my datafile is

```
1 chr1 chr1:10177 1:10177_A_AC 10177 A AC
1 chr1 chr1:10235 1:10235_T_TA 10235 T TA
1 chr1 chr1:10352 1:10352_T_TA 10352 T TA
1 chr1 chr1:10505 1:10505_A_T 10505 A T
1 chr1 chr1:10506 1:10506_C_G 10506 C G
1 chr1 chr1:10511 1:10511_G_A 10511 G A
1 chr1 chr1:10539 1:10539_C_A 10539 C A
1 chr1 chr1:10542 1:10542_C_T 10542 C T
1 chr1 chr1:10579 1:10579_C_A 10579 C A
```

The output should look like:

```
1       rs367896724     1:10177_A_AC    10177   A       AC      A       AC
1       rs540431307     1:10235_T_TA    10235   T       TA      T       TA
1       chr1:10352      1:10352_T_TA    10352   T       TA      T       TA
1       chr1:10505      1:10505_A_T     10505   A       T       A       T
1       chr1:10506      1:10506_C_G     10506   C       G       C       G
1       chr1:10511      1:10511_G_A     10511   G       A       G       A
1       chr1:10539      1:10539_C_A     10539   C       A       C       A
1       chr1:10542      1:10542_C_T     10542   C       T       C       T
1       chr1:10579      1:10579_C_A     10579   C       A       C       A
```

The awk code I have managed to get working for the sample file is as follows:

> ```
> awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"}
> NR==FNR {               #lookup file (323 million rows)
>     key = $1 "," $2 "," $4 "," $5
>     present[key] = 1
>     ID[key] = $3
>     Ref[key] = $4
>     Alt[key] = $5
>
>     key1 = $1 "," $2 "," $4 "," $5
>     present1[key1] = 1
>     ID1[key1] = $3
>     Ref1[key1] = $4
>     Alt1[key1] = $5
>
>     next
> }
> {                       # my data file (3 million rows)
>     key = $1 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7
>     key1 = $1 "," $5 "," $7 "," $6
>     if (present[key]) print $1, ID[key], $4, $5, $6, $7, Ref[key], Alt[key];
>     else if (present1[key1]) print $1, ID1[key1], $4, $5, $6, $7, Ref1[key1], Alt1[key1];
>     else              print $1, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $6, $7
> }' $lookupfile $mydatafile > $outputfile
> ```

Comment: "Merge", "huge files", "preserve order": pick two.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to add line numbers (to preserve order), and import both files in a SQL database.  Then your problem becomes a simple join.

Comment: @SatōKatsura The order of the data file is to be kept, but this is not critical. The critical part is the lookup table, but you can modify that as you like.

Comment: This is on topic here and welcome to stay. I would also expect you have a much better chance of an answer here than on [so]. That said, it might be wrong to look at this as a simple text parsing issue. it looks like you are essentially trying to attach rsIDs to a set of variants. So essentially to annotate a VCF file. Or something very similar. You might want to explain your issue from the beginning and ask on [bioinformatics.se] instead. But there, just explain what your final objective is. I am guessing there's no need to use the enormous lookup file to begin with.

Comment: One more thing. Why is the order important? In your example, it looks like you've just sorted by chromosome and position. Is that so? If yes, we can easily get the original order back by sorting again. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Thank you - it is a similar thing to a VCF file, but the order is not just chromosome / position. I have managed to solve my problem by breaking it down into chromosomes and using my original code per chromosome `for chr in 'seq 1 22; echo 'X''; do` etc - not the most elegant of solutions, but it worked!

Comment: Do I see it correctly, that both your files are sorted by chromosome, position, rs#, and allele names anyway?

Comment: Could it be there is a bug in your output file description: I suspekt in the last 4 columns you'd like to compare a1 and a2 of the two files, but if there are no matching lines in lookup file, there are also no matching alleles. Shouldn't one pair of the last four columns be empty in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not keeping that file in memory, but to scan through the lookup table for each line of the data file. Your code doesn't show it, but behind the scenes you do 3'000'000 times 323'000'000/2 = almost half a quadrillion string comparisons, moving thousands of terabytes over your memory bus. Even for fast memory with 200 GBit/s this will take many hours.

So the key to the problem is how to store the lookup table. I suggest to use a binary tree to exponentially reduce execution time. You can do this in `perl` or `C` or some other language, but at this moment it will become off-topic here.

The unix command toolset will not help you with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If my assuptions are correct, then both files are sorted by chromosome, base pair position, rs number (only lookup table) and finally alleles - at least the parts shown follow this pattern. In this case you don't need to keep the whole lookup table in memory. Instead you only need to go through each of the files once, memory requirement is negligible:

Go through each marker in the data file in turn, then search in the lookup file until you either have found a match or have run past your candidate position and thus determined that there is none. If a match is found extract the respective rs number from lookup table, otherwise just use current chr:bp combination from data table.

Using the script below I got your desired output. Save the script, and the use it like this:

```
gawk -f scriptname datafile lookuptable outputfile
```

Some small addition: to get minimal feedback on the amount of data processed one "#" and "." respectively is output for each 10,000 lines in the data and lookup tables.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f 
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    step = 10000
    while (1==1) {
        if ((getline indata < ARGV[1]) < 1)
            break
        if (!(na++ % step))
            printf "\n#"
        split(indata,a)
        allequal = 0
        while (1==1) {
            if (!overrun) {
                if ((getline inlookup < ARGV[2]) < 1)
                    break
                if (!(nb++ % step))
                    printf "."
            } else {
                overrun=0
            }
            split(inlookup,b)
            if (b[1]>a[1] || b[2]>a[5]) {
                overrun=1
                break
            }
            if (a[1]==b[1] && a[5]==b[2] && ((a[6]==b[4] && a[7]==b[5]) || (a[7]==b[4] && a[6]==b[5]))) {
                allequal=1
                break
            }   
        }
        if (allequal) {
            print a[1],b[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],b[4],b[5] > ARGV[3]
        } else {
            print a[1],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7],a[6],a[7] > ARGV[3]
        }   
    }
}
```